# Why do Apache access logs sometimes have two host ip addresses?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I have been trying to parse apache access logs but for some reason there are two host ip addresses separated by a comma and a space. I am thinking of just removing the second ip address, does it mean anything? I would hate to remove something that might have useful information.

edit:

Here is an example of the log line with two ip addresses:

```
62.28.25.X, 194.65.37.X - - [06/May/2014:17:58:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1556 "http://mysite.io/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; chromeframe/32.0.1700.107; GTB7.5; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"
```

A normal line:

```
54.247.188.X - - [08/May/2014:00:04:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "-" "NewRelicPinger/1.0 (625386)"
```

I do not have mod_log_config in my mods-enabled directory. Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place? It should just be the default.

edit2:

I found this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, I hope this clears things up.

```
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

Comment: Please show an example of the logs (good and 'bad'). Please also show us your `customlog` directives.

Comment: Without seeing your `customlog` directive I couldn't say with any certainty, but it's probably a proxied request and the log is showing both the proxy and the original client.

Comment: Read the documentation for customlog it will tell you where to look for the directives. Do you recognise any of the IP addresses and if so what is the purpose of the box they are on ?

Answer (score 8):

This happens when Apache receives a connection from a system that is (or claims to be) a proxy. The `%h` format specifier normally produces just an IP address, but when the client sends a header indicating that it has proxied the request, the IP of the original client is recorded with a comma, and then the IP of the proxy.